# Python wont save compressed string using zlib

Tags: python, string, file, compression, zlib

According to this [website and guide](https://stackabuse.com/python-zlib-library-tutorial/) it should  be pretty trivial to save the string as compressed using zlib.

```
import zlib

my_data = 'Hello world'

compressed_data = zlib.compress(my_data, 2)

f = open('outfile.txt', 'w')
f.write(compressed_data)
f.close()
```

This code should save "Hello world" into txt file as compressed. I'm getting these errors:

> compressed_data = zlib.compress(my_data, 2)

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I have also tried adding this but then i get other error saying

```
new_data = zlib.compress(my_data.encode())
compressed_data = zlib.compress(new_data, 2)
```

And then i get errors like this:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

I have also tried adding b' in front of the text in my_data but that gave me new error

```
my_data = b'Hello world'
```

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you found deep in the bowels of the interwebs is for Python 2, not Python 3. Python 3 makes a distinction between strings of characters and strings of bytes. All is well with the addition of two "b"s:

```
import zlib
my_data = b'Hello world'
compressed_data = zlib.compress(my_data, 2)
f = open('outfile.txt', 'wb')
f.write(compressed_data)
f.close()
```

By the way, I have no idea why they wanted to use compression level 2. Just leave out the `, 2`. It will then use the default compression level, which is a good balance between time and compression ratio.